# scrlttr2 Remove large gap when not specifying to address

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I'm writing a cover letter using the `scrlttr2` class. I don't have a to address because it is addressed to a committee. Since I don't have a to address, there is a large white gap where the address should be and I'd like to remove it. **How?**

My MWE is below

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=DarkBlue]{hyperref}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
  My address
  Somewhere, ST 12345
}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{800-867-5309}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{myemail@gmail.com}
\setkomavar{signature}{My Name}
% \setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\KOMAoptions{
  paper=letter,
  backaddress=off,
  fromalign=right,
  addrfield=off,
  fromphone=on,
  foldmarks=false,
  fromemail=true,
  addrfield=off,
  fromrule=aftername,
}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \Large}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=1.5em}

\newcommand{\skillitem}[1]{ {\bfseries \sffamily #1} }

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
  \opening{To Whom it May Concern,}

  \closing{Sincerely,}
  \cc{Someone else, someone@gmail.com}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the vertical position of the reference line (or the line with the date). Therefore you have to adjust the pseudo-length `refvpos`.

For more information regarding pseudo-lengths and the commands `\@setplength`, `\@addtoplength` and `\useplength` see the KOMA-Script documentation, section 22.1. Pseudo-Lengths for Experienced Users. There is also a figure showing the pseudo-lengths.

**Examples:**

You could set `refvpos` to the value of `toaddrvpos`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
  My address
  Somewhere, ST 12345
}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{800-867-5309}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{myemail@gmail.com}
\setkomavar{signature}{My Name}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\KOMAoptions{
  paper=letter,
  backaddress=off,
  fromalign=right,
  addrfield=off,
  fromphone=on,
  foldmarks=false,
  fromemail=true,
  addrfield=off,
  fromrule=aftername,
}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \Large}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}% <- added
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
  \opening{To Whom it May Concern,}
  \closing{Sincerely,}
  \cc{Someone else, someone@gmail.com}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Or you can shift it up by `toaddrheight`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
  My address
  Somewhere, ST 12345
}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{800-867-5309}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{myemail@gmail.com}
\setkomavar{signature}{My Name}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\KOMAoptions{
  paper=letter,
  backaddress=off,
  fromalign=right,
  addrfield=off,
  fromphone=on,
  foldmarks=false,
  fromemail=true,
  addrfield=off,
  fromrule=aftername,
}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \Large}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}l
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\@addtoplength[-]{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrheight}}% <- added
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
  \opening{To Whom it May Concern,}
  \closing{Sincerely,}
  \cc{Someone else, someone@gmail.com}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

**Additional remark**

The **next KOMA-Script version 3.26** will introduce the commands `\newplength`, `\setplength` and `\addtoplength` (note the missing `@`). Then you can use these commands without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the examples above.

Comment: This works. I wish it was more obvious about how to do this.

Comment: See the KOMA-Script documentation, section 22.1. Pseudo-Lengths for Experienced Users.